# How to run a docker image in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I know how to build a docker image in Jenkins.  Basically, calling `docker.build("foo")` from my Jenkinsfile is the equivalent of executing, from the command line, `docker build -t foo .`.

My question is how I RUN the image?  What's the equivalent of `docker run foo`, assuming that `foo` has a defined `ENTRYPOINT`?

I'm familiar with `docker.image('foo').inside() { ... }`, which allows me to run a shell script or something inside the container, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to run the container from it's `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 2):

For running a Docker image from jenkinsfile you can use the below docker CLI commmand-

```
sh "docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash example"
```

It will start the docker container (run docker image) and you can ssh to the host where docker is running and can use `docker ps` command to list the running container.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably have a look at `.withRun` -

Run a normal command OR use your entrypoint as argument -

```
docker.image('python:2.7').withRun('-u root --entrypoint /bin/bash') {
    sh 'pip install version'
}
```